# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type x to type y

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a custom messaging system which I am trying to convert so it can support plugins.

The system has producers and consumers.
Both must specify the type of message they produce or consume.

For consumers the Interface to be implemented is

```
IConsumer<AMessage>
```

I have a consumer in a plugin dll which implements this Interface:

```
FileProcessor : IConsumer<FileMessage>
```

With

```
FileMessage : AMessage
```

And AMessage is an abstract class.
Both IConsumer and AMessage are in the main (Core) assembly.

Now, in the core, which loaded the plugin and scanned & found the consumers I want to link the consumers into the messaging system.

To simplify things here I just try to put the consumer in a variable:

```
IConsumer<AMessage> consumer = IConsumer<AMessage> new FileProcessor();
```

I get a warning in VS:

> Suspicious cast:there is no type in the solution which is inherited
>   from both 'TestPlugin.FileProcessor' and 'Core.IConsumer'.

And when I execute I get

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'TestPlugin.FileProcessor' to type 'Core.IConsumer`1[Core.AMessage]'.

Why does this cast fail? How can I solve this?

**--edit1--**

based on comments, here is the full definition of IProducer and IConsumer:

```
public interface IProducer<out T> : IProcessor where T : AMessage
{
    event MessageSender<T> SendMessage;
}

public interface IConsumer<in T> : IProcessor where T : AMessage
{
    ProcessResult ProcessBean(T bean);
}
```

when Producers are linked in the system, they define T, after that only consumers with the same type of T can be linked to that producer.
For example:

```
var channel = flow.From(FileProducer).To(FileConsumer);
```

With flow.From:

```
public Channel<T> From<T>(IProducer<T> producer) where T : AMessage
{
    ...
}
```

and channel.To:

```
public class Channel<T> where T : AMessage 
{

   public Channel<T> To(IConsumer<T> consumer){
      ...
   }
}
```

So the producer defines the type of T for the consumers.

**--edit1--**

**--edit2--**

The need for the down-cast is because I am trying to reconstruct the channels from an JSON definition in the Core system.

So Consumers (and Producers) are dynamically constructed from the plugins assemblies and added to a temporary dictionary (when detected and instantiated):

```
var consumers = new Dictionary<string, IProcessor>();
```

I cannot use IConsumer here for the consumers since T is not necessarily the same for all consumers.

Then when building the Channels, I'll lookup the consumer by it's id (key of dictionary) and provide it to the To(...) method of the channel. That fails because the dictionary holds IProcessor and the dynamically constructed channel has a "To" signature of  `public Channel<T> To(IConsumer<T> consumer)`.

**--edit2--**

**--solution--**

Thanks to Luaan (see comments) I reached to the following solution:

When scanning the plugin assemblies I originally stored the detected Producers and Consumers in a dictionary of `<string, IProcessor>`, now I changed this dictionary to `<string, dynamic>` which solved this casting issue!

Thanks to all who added to getting to this solution!

@Luaan, I wished I could select your answer as the solution, but it is in a comment...

**--solution--**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* that `FileProcessor`, presumably written to consume `FileMessages`, can cope with being passed *any* kind of `AMessage`?

Comment: 'FileProcessor' cannot consume just any AMessage, only FileMessage. But that is handled by the system. When a producer is linked in the system, a channel is created with the same AMessage type of the producer. Then the channel only accepts consumers having the same AMessage type as the producer (all done with generics).

Comment: The fact that you get a warning and a cast exception implies the system/generics aren't handling this properly. If the channel only needs consumers of the correct type, you shouldn't have to cast to the general type.

Comment: Could you add some code around the cast - tell us why you need to cast to the general consumer type?

Comment: I added --edit2--. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: `IConsumer<FileMessage>` is *not* convertible to `IConsumer<AMessage>`. If it were, you'd be able to pass an `AMessage` instead of `FileMessage`, which is not something you want :)

Comment: @Luaan, ok, I understand, but how do I keep the consumers temporarily in a dictionary in order to be able to link then in the system? (see edit2 of my post)

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a simple problem. Generics are both compile-time and run-time type-safe, so everything you've tried must fail, since you're breaking type safety. A simple (though not necessarily a *good*) solution might be to use `dynamic` to handle the specific consumer and producer types - this allows you to defer the type resolution to runtime, which will make your code work. It also introduces a lot of its own problems of course, and deferring the work to runtime means less compile-time checking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark your interface as [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `out` keyword:

```
IConsumer<out AMessage>
```

This means you can pass a more derived type than the one specified, so you can use a `FileMessage` which derives from `AMessage`.

Seeing your edits, you don't need covariance but contravariance (`IConsumer<in AMessage>`) but then this cast:

```
IConsumer<AMessage> consumer = (IConsumer<AMessage>)new FileProcessor();
```

isn't valid. From msdn:

> Contravariance
>   Enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally specified.
>   **You can assign an instance of IEnumerable<Base> to a variable of type IEnumerable<Derived>.**

Comment: I am wary of whether something called a *consumer* should have `out` instead of `in`, but on the face of it this is what the asker wants...

Comment: @Rawling Well there's not much code to work with so I don't know what he's trying to accomplish, but it does make the cast he wants valid

Comment: The consumer indeed needs to have `in`. I'll add the definition to my post.

Answer (score 0):

If in your `IConsumer<T>` interface the `T` occurs only in return values, then you can make your interface covariant (in .NET 4 and above):

```
public interface IConsumer<out T>
```

In this case this initialization will work:

```
IConsumer<AMessage> consumer = new FileProcessor();
```

But if `T` is used in method parameters as well, then your interface cannot be covariant. Which is good so, see `IList<T>`, for example: If `IList<Animal> cats = new List<Cat>()` would be allowed, you could call `cats.Add(new Dog())`, which is not desired. :)